# sql statement to update table using variable

Tags: sql

```
String sql1 = 
" UPDATE filename SET @count=@valu2 where @name12=@fname1 ";
stmt = connection_ms.con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

Here `valu2` and `fname1` are variable it gives error

Comment: Verify that values in variables '@count' and '@name12' are indeed column names which you want to use from table 'filename'. And then verify that values in variables '@valu2'  and '@fname1' have compatible data types with their corresponding database columns.

Answer (score 0):

make it like below

```
sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("your connection string");
string sql1 ="UPDATE filename SET @count=@valu2 where @name12=@fname1 ";
sqlcommand com=new sqlcommand(sql1,con);
com.parameters.addwithvalue("@valu2","enter valu2 here");
com.parameters.addwithvalue("@fname1 ","enter fname1  here");
con.open();
com.executenonquery();
con.close();
```